# Sorting list of tuples based on multiple keys and returning top results

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list like that:

```
[
('abilty', 'ability', 14, 1), 
('aand', 'wand', 14, 1), 
('aand', 'sand', 14, 1), 
('aand', 'land', 272, 1), 
('aand', 'hand', 817, 1), 
('aand', 'and', 38093, 1), 
('aand', 'band', 38093, 1), 
('aand', 'iand', 38093, 1), 
('aand', 'fand', 38093, 1)]
```

In this list for one word if there are more than one value (for example there are 8 match for aand )then I want to sort them according to 3rd attribute and choose the first highest one. For example in this sample my result should be

```
[
('abilty', 'ability', 14, 1),  
('aand', 'and', 38093, 1), 
]
```

I try something but unfortunately it does not work. Could you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort the list:

```
>>> new_lis = sorted(lis,key=lambda x : (x[0],x[2]),reverse = True) #lis is your list

>>> new_lis
[('abilty', 'ability', 14, 1), ('aand', 'and', 38093, 1), ('aand', 'band', 38093, 1), ('aand', 'iand', 38093, 1), ('aand', 'fand', 38093, 1), ('aand', 'hand', 817, 1), ('aand', 'land', 272, 1), ('aand', 'wand', 14, 1), ('aand', 'sand', 14, 1)]
```

Now to get only one item per group use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [next(v) for k,v in groupby(new_lis,key=lambda x:x[0])]
[('abilty', 'ability', 14, 1), ('aand', 'and', 38093, 1)]
```

Total complexity of above method is `O(NlogN)`.

You can also use `collections.defauldict` here, complexity `O(N)`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic=defaultdict(list)
>>> for x in lis:
...     dic[x[0]].append(x)
...     
>>> [max(val,key=lambda x: x[2]) for val in dic.values()]
[('aand', 'and', 38093, 1), ('abilty', 'ability', 14, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itemgetter` as in this example

```
>>> student_tuples = [
        ('john', 'A', 15),
        ('jane', 'B', 12),
        ('dave', 'B', 10),
]

>>> from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(2))
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

For you it comes to

```
l=[
('abilty', 'ability', 14, 1), 
('aand', 'wand', 14, 1), 
('aand', 'sand', 14, 1), 
('aand', 'land', 272, 1), 
('aand', 'hand', 817, 1), 
('aand', 'and', 38093, 1), 
('aand', 'band', 38093, 1), 
('aand', 'iand', 38093, 1), 
('aand', 'fand', 38093, 1)]

from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

sorted_l = sorted(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(2), reverse = True)

s = ''

for x in sorted_l:
    if (x[0] != s):
        s = x[0]
        print x
```